# Proper JavaScript line breaking?

Tags: javascript

Is breaking up a long boolean expression like this

```
var x = a === b && c === d && e === f;
```

To something more readable like

```
var x = a === b
        && c === d
        && e === f;
```

considered bad practice?
With long variable names the former can become extremely long.

Comment: Write a function in this case to make it short and clean. Like ```var x = computeX();``` .

Comment: Various companies have style guides. It depends on your preference.

https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml
http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: I would always put the operators on the end of the line to prevent the interpreter forcing a semicolon where I don't want it.
Reading: http://benalman.com/news/2013/01/advice-javascript-semicolon-haters/

Comment: fwiw, I write (and see) that style kind of style all the time in other languages: java, perl, c.  Be advised that I haven't written enough javascript to phrase this in an actual answer, so just a comment.

Answer (score 5):

You are free to put line breaks in an expression like this.  It is not considered a bad practice.  In fact, it's a good practice to keep your code readable without lots of horizontal scrolling so if some line breaks are required in order to do that, then it is recommended.

Many corporate coding style guides specify a max code line length for easy reading and line breaks like this are required in order to follow those types of guidelines.

Check out Douglas Crockford's javascript conventions or even Google's Style Guide with a select quote from each:

[Google JavaScript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml)

> When possible, all function arguments should be listed on the same
>               line. If doing so would exceed the 80-column limit, the arguments
>               must be line-wrapped in a readable way. To save space, you may wrap
>               as close to 80 as possible, or put each argument on its own line to
>               enhance readability. The indentation may be either four spaces, or
>               aligned to the parenthesis.

[Crockford's Code Conventions for the JavaScript Programming Language](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)

> Avoid excessively long lines. When a statement will not fit nicely on
>   a single line, it may be necessary to break it. It is best to break
>   after a { left brace, [ left bracket, ( left paren, , comma, or before
>   a . period, ? question mark, or : colon. If such a break is not
>   feasible, then break after an operator and continue on the next line
>   with 8 spaces added to the current indentation. Those 8 spaces do not
>   change the current indentation.

[MDN Coding Style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Coding_Style)

> Line length
>
> 80 characters or less (for laptop side-by-side diffing and two-window
>   tiling

Comment: @toro - Did this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  If not, then please explain what you still need help with.

Answer (score 1):

Write a function in this case to make it short and clean. It is because that we should hide the details and only write the code with same abstract layer in one function (suggested in the book "Clean Code").

So,

```
var x = computeX();
...
function computeX() {
  var logic1 = (a === b);
  var logic2 = (c === d);
  var logic3 = (e === f);
  return logic1 && logic2 && logic3;
}
```

Make sure you also give them good names.

Comment: Note that if you are trying to optimize your code, you don't want to do this, but that's what's UglifyJS is for :)

Comment: There's generally little cause to put something simple like this into a function that is only ever called once in your code.  Nothing wrong with an inline expression.  This function doesn't actually make the code any simpler to read.  The same boolean logic expression must be understood either way.

Comment: @jfriend00 I disagree. As long as you name things semantically, this *does* make the code simpler to read, e.g. a function like this can be called something like `doesRequireUserField()`, and the details of how that value is determined can be something that the implementation doesn't have to be aware of.

Comment: @zakangelle - You're welcome to your opinion.  I have a different opinion.  I tend to only put single use things off into a function if there is so much code that it overwhelms the complexity of understanding the containing function.  If find it hard to believe that a relatively simple three term boolean expression meets any criteria about being too complex to easily render and follow inline.  Keep in mind, this is a three term boolean expression, nothing more.